# Previous adjacent selector in CSS

Tags: css

Is there are way in CSS to target every `p` preceding a `div.carrots`? In this case we would get *Munch* but not *Burp*.

```
<p>Munch Munch!</p>
<div class="carrots">
</div>

<p>Burp!</p>
<div class="potatoes">
</div>
```

Comment: The specification at http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors has a list of all the selectors. It should be easy to see that what you want isn't in the list.

Comment: Oops, that was CSS2. Here's CSS3: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors

Answer (score 0):

There is no "previous sibling" selector.  Only The [adjacent and general combinators](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#adjacent-sibling-combinators), which require the target sibling to be *after* the first.

In order to select `<p>` in this case, you can surround the contents with some element (say, `.container` and use `.container p:first-child` as the selector.  I don't think things would be all that different if you did this either:

```
<div class=carrots>
    <p>Munch Munch!</p>
    <div>
    </div>
</div>
```