# jQuery: is there a previous Adjacent Selector similar to the Next Adjacent Selector (prev + next)?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to select the immediately preceding sibling of an element using jQuery.

I am aware of jQuery's .prev() selector but I was wondering if there is an equivalent to the [Next Adjacent Selector (prev + next)](http://api.jquery.com/next-adjacent-selector/) - essentially a **Previous Adjacent Selector (current + prev)** or something like it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Short answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/css-previous-sibling-selector): [no.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20624483/previous-adjacent-selector-in-css)

[This works though](http://jsfiddle.net/8rfD2/):

```
<p>Hello world!</p> <!-- gets selected class -->
<p id="selector">Hello world!</p>
<p>Hello world!</p>

$('#selector').prev().addClass('selected');
```

Comment: Here's a good fiddle from the "short answer" link's accepted answer comments: http://jsfiddle.net/NuuHy/1/

Comment: @Loïc Mettre des espaces avant les signes de ponctuation, c'est une convention typographique française. En anglais, on ne met jamais d'espace avant la ponctuation.

Comment: Ah ok, merci de l'info.